# JavaFX How to use my own .jar library in another project?

Tags: mysql, javafx, itext

I made my own javafx library "GeneratingPDF" with implemented "iText" lib and one main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String file_name = "Client_list.pdf";
            Document document = new Document();

            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file_name));

            document.open();
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph("List of clients: \n\n\n");
            document.add(para);
            if(args.length > 0){
                for(String arg : args) {
                    document.add(new Paragraph(arg));
                    System.out.println("Arg added");
                }
            }
            document.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This library gets a list of arguments and generates a PDF document from them. I've got another javafx project with button "Generate Raport" and onAction method  which I pasted below. I've already added my library to the project. I want to retrieve customer information from my database and send it to my library that will generate a PDF file. What should I add to this method? How to use in code my own "GeneratingPDF.jar" lib?

```
public void generateRaport(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/projekt_zespolowe?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");

            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            String query="SELECT * FROM client";
            ps=connection.prepareStatement(query);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                //(rs.getString("client_id")+ " "+rs.getString("login")+ " "+rs.getString("name")+ " "+rs.getString("surname")+ " "+rs.getString("date_birth")+ " "+rs.getString("city"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You use your own library like you'd use any other library. I'm not sure I understand the problem?

Comment: So, how should I call this main method from my own lib?

Comment: _From_ your own library? You don't. Your current project has a dependency on your library, not the other way around. You should be calling functions in your library to use its functionality. You do that by importing the needed classes and calling the needed methods.